# Bake texture with Mapping node coordinates?

Tags: baking

I have these exact shading settings and I would like to bake the textures exactly with the Mapping node coordinates so I can export it to Unity.

[image]

I tried baking the normals but the result texture became strange as soon as I disconnected the Mapping node. I need it to look exactly how it looks with this configuration but just with the texture image node, so I can use it in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but my instinct would be to plug the output of the Bump node into an emission shader, and bake the emission into the original UV map? (Taking care to be in a linear color-space .. saving to Open EXR)